# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?' when making discord bot in JavaScript on repl.it

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am getting an error:

```
const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;
                                 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

Code For Discord Bot:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "ping") {
    msg.reply("pong")
  }
})

client.login("my token here")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to the FreeCodeCamp tutorial [Code a Discord Bot with JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rU_KyudGBY). You can actually use the repl.it shell to solve this. Go to the shell (the tab on the right of the console tab) and enter `npm i discord.js@12.5.3`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

From your error message, in

```
const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;
```

the code in the discord library uses `??`, the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) that is only available in node.js v14.0.0 and later. I saw that the default node.js environment that is available on `repl.it` is only v12.16.1.

To make your code run, you can either find an old version of `discord.js` that still works with node 12, or you could follow some guide to manually install a new node environment (I found https://replit.com/talk/learn/Nodejs-14-on-replit/85501)