# Unexpected token '?' discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm facing an error while hosting my discord bot on repl.it

I get this error,

```yaml
/home/runner/JU-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:32
    const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

It works perfectly fine on my local machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am trying to make a discord bot in java script on repl.it but it gives me an error error above code below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68707306/i-am-trying-to-make-a-discord-bot-in-java-script-on-repl-it-but-it-gives-me-an-e)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That `??` is the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). Your error means you're running a version of node.js that does not support it.  You'll want to upgrade to at least node version 14 to access this feature. Unfortunately, **repl.it [does not support](https://replit.com/talk/ask/change-node-version/5924) upgrading to a newer version** unless there is already a version for it when creating the repo.

Answer (score 3):

To use the latest version of the DiscordJS library you will actually need Node v16+.

I tried to run a server application instance on Vercel that used DiscordJS but it uses Node version 14.x runtime. This ended up as an error and you need to use/host your server in an environment that is Node version 16.x+.