# Why does it output an error: "Unexpected token: '?' " in discord.js replit?

Tags: discord.js

I wanted to use replit to make my discord bot. I installed discord.js on the node.js replit. I inserted this code in the index.js:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("If you can see this in the console when you run it on replit, I will be shocked lol")
});


client.login(process.env["BOT_TOKEN"]);
```

Somehow, it outputs an error. It states:
const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken
Syntax error: Unexpected token: '?'

Thank you,
Paul10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am trying to make a discord bot in JavaScript on repl.it but it gives me an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68707306/i-am-trying-to-make-a-discord-bot-in-javascript-on-repl-it-but-it-gives-me-an-er)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because repl.it uses an old version of Node.js that doesn't support the `??` operator. I suggest following this tutorial:

https://replit.com/talk/learn/Nodejs-14-on-replit/85501